# What does "Other" mean for Traffic Source on Google Analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I logged into Google Analytics today and under 'Traffic Sources' saw: "Referring sites", "Direct Traffic", "Search Engines" and "Other". I've never seen 'other' before, and it was small (only 0.5%), but what does "Other" mean?

Answer (score 6):

'Other' means traffic sent from:

- Email clients, via email campaigns or people sharing links to your site by email.
- [Tagged links](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578) for any marketing campaigns you run.

Answer (score 0):

'Other', in this case, is defined by exclusion.

- Referring Sites is defined by traffic where GA could detect `document.referrer`, and thus set the medium as `referral`, except if deemed as search engine traffic or overridden with manual campaign tagging.
- Search Engines is defined by referral traffic that `ga.js` has explicitly determined to be search traffic, as well as tagged traffic where `utm_medium` is set to either `cpc` or `organic`.
- Direct Traffic is defined as traffic without a referrer and no campaign tagging. This could come from manual URL entry, from an HTTPS->HTTP referral, from a non-web source (like an app), etc.
- Other is any traffic that has defined sources that doesn't meet any of the above criteria.